# Нужно ли указывать лицензию на задействованные библиотеки в проекте?

Tags: библиотеки, лицензирование

Собираюсь создать небольшое приложение на Android Studio, затем выложить его как портфолио на github. Нужно ли указывать лицензию на импортированные классы и библиотеки? (импорт все-таки довольно частая процедура при создании проектов) Если нужно, то каким образом? И будут ли последствия, если например случайно что-то не забыл и не указал?

Comment: посмотрите, как делают большие компании - просто указывают список всех библиотек и лицензии/ссылки на них. В принципе это можно даже автоматизировать. С другой стороны, если библиотеку импортируете корректно (а не выборочной копипастой) и сорцы все видны, то и лицензия на каждую библиотеку тоже будет видна.

Comment: `И будут ли последствия, если например случайно что-то не забыл и не указал?` - скорее всего Вам просто напишут, мол "не указано". Просто добавите и все будет хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim, просто я находил  проекты, где на стандартные библиотеки для android (например androidx, context, intent и др), они были импортированы, но не было никаких указаний на них, просто  один общий файл лицензии на весь проект в корневой папке и все.

Comment: это не совсем "библиотеки". Вы же в лицензии не собираетесь указывать использование int, char?

Comment: @KoVadim, ну вот каких-то крупных сторонних библиотек я не использовал, в основном, какие-то стандартные вещи, которые входят в Android SDK. Я начинающий и многого еще не знаю. Возможно, еще я многого не понимаю, просто сейчас кажется что лучше вообще лицензию не добавлять, а проблемы если возникнут, то решать их по мере их поступления.

Comment: Я думаю, что это очевидно, что Вы используете android sdk - без него немного сложновато.

Comment: @KoVadim, кстати, по поводу тех же int, char, ну то есть типов данных. Их вроде бы не нужно импортировать, в отличие например от Activity, Layout, Intent, View, различного рода адаптеры и прочее что входит в android/androidx. Поэтому и подумал, что эти вещи тоже нужно как-то указывать.